# Uniqueness of C* norm and tensor product of C* algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I am little bit confuse about the norms defined on tensor product of C* algebra. We can define spatial norm and maximal norm on $A\otimes B$ for $A,B$ are C* algebras. However there is theorem telling us that C* norm is unique on an algebra, what am I missing here?

Comment: If an involutive algebra admits the structure of a C* algebra then there is a unique norm on it satisfying the C* identity - ie the algebra admits only one C* structure. For the tensor norms note that $A\otimes B$ does **not** (usually) admit the structure of a C*-algebra, rather there are some norms on it that satisfy the C* identity and when you take the **completion** wrt these norms you can put on this completion the structure of a C* algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the theorem. The theorem says:

**Theorem:** There is at most one $C^*$-norm on a $*$-algebra $A$ such that $A$ becomes a $C^*$-algebra.

In general, a $*$-algebra can carry a lot of $C^*$-norms. The subtlety here is that a $*$-algebra together with a $C^*$-norm is not a $C^*$-algebra: the $*$-algebra need not be a complete normed space with respect to this $*$-norm.

Given two $C^*$-algebra $A$ and $B$, we can form the algebraic tensor product $A \odot B$. If $A$ and $B$ are both infinite-dimensional, $A \odot B$ will in general not be complete and thus not a $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: Nice answer. I would like to add: As explained, we can have many $C^*$-norms on a $*$-algebra. Yes, if the $*$-algebra is complete with respect to one of them, then it is unique. In general this is not true, as said in the last 2 lines of this answer. So the $C^*$-tensor products are defined as the *completions* of the star-algebra $A\odot B$ with respect to each $C^*$-norm. So the $C^*$-tensor products of $A$ and $B$ are different $C^*$-algebras; what they do have in common though is that they all have the algebraic tensor product $A\odot B$ as a dense (each for its own norm) $*$-subalgebra.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn One can further add that the class of $C^*$-algebras $A$ such that $A \odot B$ has a unique $C^*$-norm for every $C^*$-algebra $B$ are called the nuclear $C^*$-algebras. So, if we want to find an explicit example of a $C^*$-algebra where $A \odot B$ has different $C^*$-norms, we have to lookin within the class of non-nuclear $C^*$-algebras. Probably the easiest such example is the reduced group $C^*$-algebra $C_\lambda^*(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is a non-amenable discrete group, for instance $\Gamma = \mathbb{F}_2$, the free group on two generators.